# riley is depressed

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> I take my prefix because I am my infix.
>
> I am nobody, that's why I feel my suffix.
>
> I will never get up, I'll lie with my whole.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are a:

> **PILLOW**

*I take my prefix because I am my infix.*

> You take a **PILL** because you are **ILL**.

*I am nobody, that's why I feel my suffix.*

> You sound pretty sad - you must feel **LOW**.

*I will never get up, I'll lie with my whole.*

> Stay in bed and lie with your **PILLOW**...

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @riskymysteries - Happy New Year! :)